# Get and Display Title of Element

Tags: jquery

I have several images on a page, all in list items. On hover of one of those images, I would like to get the `title` attribute and display it in a div. Here's my code so far:

```
<ul>
    <li><img src="1.jpg" title="First Image"></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg" title="A second Image"></li>
    <li><img src="3.jpg" title="And another one"></li>
</ul>

<div id="imagetitle">
<!-- Title Should go Here -->
</div>
```

I have a general idea that you could do this with the `attr();` in jQuery, but I'm not sure how — can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bind a `hover` event. Then, modify the contents of the `#imagetitle` div using `.text()`. You can retrieve the title through `this.title` *or, if you wish, `$(this).attr('title')`.*

```
$('img').hover(function(){
    $('#imagetitle').text(this.title);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('li').live('hover',function() {
    $title = $(this).find('img').attr('title');
    //alert($title);  
    $('#imagetitle').html($title);  
});
```

[`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/47LfY/)